# Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow-gpu (from versions: none)

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip, virtualenv

I am learning how to create virtual environment with the (great) video of Nicholas Renotte : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=19LQRx78QVU&list=PLgNJO2hghbmiXg5d4X8DURJP9yv9pgjIu&index=1

Until 35:10, everything is fine I succeed all the steps : create a virtual environment, install ipykernel inside, open Jupyter lab.

Then, in Jupyter Lab, I succeeded installing TensorFlow but when I am installing TensorFlow-gpu I have an error which I do not know how to correct it.

[image]

Do you have an idea of how I could correct this error ? Thanks in advance for your help and your time.

Comment: On which system you are running this notebook cell?

Comment: on a Jupyter lab in the virtual environment that I created on my macOS

Comment: Is it a MacOS with M1?

Comment: Yeah, I have the M1 Pro

Answer (score 0):

The reason this error is that currently there is no official GPU support for running TensorFlow on MacOS.
However you can try setting up the tensorflow CPU in your system by following the steps mentioned in [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#step-by-step_instructions) link.